# Importance of WAP version of web system

Tags: web-development

What is the importance of WAP version of web systems? to cater those mobile phones that does not support standard HTML pages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as [wikipedia says](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_Application_Protocol), wap was mainly designed for internet-access with mobile-phones. this doesn't apply to modern smartphones as all of them are using browsers that fully support http, so theres no need for wap anymore.

that said and reading the [section about the "commercial status" of wap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_Application_Protocol#Commercial_status), it's (nearly) dead - either people have a smartphone for mobile browsing or they don't event want mobile internet access.